# How to change the mouse cursor when mouse leaves a dynamically generated Rect in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouseleave, rect, mouse-cursor

I have a piece of code which does this:
"Creates two rectangles using Rect class in WPF and positions them on the left and bottom borders of a label to indicate whether the mouse pointer is placed within either of them, in order to resize the label if the user click and drags in those areas"

The code looks like:

```
//the event handler
private void thelabel_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
         //if the mouse button is not pressed
            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
            //locate the current mouse location
                Point currentLocation = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this);

        //the label's position
           Point labelposition = thelabel.TransformToAncestor(thegrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        //create two Rects with 3 pixels as width and just as long as each one's corresponding border, and position them on each bottom and left borders of the label
           var bottomHandle = new Rect(labelposition.X - thelabel.Width, labelposition.Y + thelabel.Height, thelabel.Width, 3);  
           var leftHandle = new Rect(labelposition.X - thelabel.Width, labelposition.Y, 3, thelabel.Height);

           Point relativeLocation = this.TranslatePoint(currentLocation, this);

        //if the left handle contains the mouse location i.e the mouse is on the left handle
           if (leftHandle.Contains(relativeLocation))
             {
                 this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
             }
          //if the bottom handle contains the mouse location
             else if (bottomHandle.Contains(relativeLocation))
             {
                 this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
             }
             else
             {
              //but this doesn't work when the mouse leaves the label and the two rects !
                 this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
             }
    }
```

The last line of code

```
else
                     {
                         this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                     }
```

doesn't work because when the mouse is **NOT** on the label, it's `OnMouseMove` is no longer called **AND** the cursor won't change back to arrow.

I've tried and added an `OnMouseMove` to the `Grid` as well as the `Canvas` containing the label and it's `Rect`s , in order to change the cursor back to arrow. But this affected on determining if the mouse is located on either of the `Rect`s.

**SO**
the question is 'how I can determine if the mouse leaves the two Rects, either from outside the label's OnMouseMove event **OR** by any other means'.

Comment: I think `this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow` in the `MouseLeave-EventHandler` of the label should do it.

Comment: No it doesn't :/  
Because one or two pixels of those Rects are outside the boundaries of the Label ...

Comment: Are you using Rectangles and are those Rectangles children of the Canvas? If yes, use Clemens solution, if no, mine should work. Regardless how much of the Rects is outside, the mousemove-event doesnt get fired outside the label.

Comment: Actually I'm using `Rects`. I assume there are a little different (rects and rectangles).
But yes, I add them to a `Canvas`.
Thanks for the advice. I'll try them both and let you know which one worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Canvas containing ... Rects" i guess you mean [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s.

In order to implement dragging, you should attach event handlers to those Rectangles (instead of the Label) for the following mouse events:

- MouseEnter - set dragging cursor
- MouseLeave - reset cursor
- MouseDown or MouseLeftButtonDown - start dragging by [capturing the
  mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx),
- MouseUp or MouseLeftButtonUp - end dragging by [releasing the mouse
  capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture.aspx)
- MouseMove - actual dragging

Comment: I guess they are different. `Rect` uses `System.Windows` namespace but `Rectangle` uses `System.Drawing`.  
And there are a few more ways to create a new instance of Rect, rather than Rectangle.
Resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx
I will try your solution and feedback right here. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: I mean `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`, a WPF Shape. A Canvas can not "contain" `System.Windows.Rect` child objects. They might however be drawn in `Canvas.OnRender`. I'm curious how you would "add" Rects to a Canvas.